# SAS DATE and TIME Conversion

Tags: date, time, sas

I have a question in merging two tables by the date/time.

In table A, the format of variable 'dt1' is '20140127', where the type is numeric;
In table B, the format of variable 'dt2' is '27JAN2014', where the type is date.

What function can I use so they can be corresponding to each other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting all your date variables stored as SAS dates so you can use the standard date functions with them. E.g.

```
data _null_;
 a1 = 20140127;
 a2 = '27jan2014'd
 b = input(a1,yymmdd8.);
 format a: b yymmdd10.;
 put _all_;
run;
```

Comment: I just tried as following, where STAY_DT_KEY is in the format '20140127'. And it returns ....... not the SAS date. Thanks!    data test5;
set RMREPORT.staypace3;
stay_date = input(STAY_DT_KEY, yymmdd8.);
format STAY_DT_KEY: stay_date yymmdd10.;
run;